# Java Component.show() / hide() are deprecated ... why?

Tags: java, swing, deprecated

Does anyone know the reason why these Java swing methods are deprecated :

```
Component.show(); 
Component.hide();
```

Answer (score 27):

JDK 1.1 introduced Java Beans.  Java Beans rely in reflection and introspection to determine what the properties of a Bean are (a Bean is a "component").  Properties are then displayed in a Property Sheet.

By default beans use the following foormat:

```
boolean isXXX()
<type> getXXX()
void setXXX(<type>)
```

(going from memory on these next two... they are for indexed properties)

```
<type> getXXX(int)
void setXXX(<type>, int)
```

You can override the defaults, but rather than do that most things just rely on the naming pattern.

So show/hide didn't conform to the naming pattern and were replaced with setVisible(boolean) which did.

Comment: Well, that is true, but what prevents a bean from having a method with pretty darn good name?

Comment: I thought may be because show and hide methods don't send PropertyChangeEvents -- but setVisible doesn't do that either ....

Comment: Bit late to the party, but I had the same question as TS. Although I think @TofuBeer is correct, another advantage the setXX has is that you can directly pass a boolean to setVisible, instead of having to call either show() or hide() in an if-then block.

Answer (score 15):

Most likely because they don't conform to the standard get/set naming scheme ([they](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#hide()) [say](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#show()), "As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by [`setVisible(boolean)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible(boolean))").

Answer (score 3):

As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Component.setVisible(boolean).

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternative: `someUseFrame.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

The hide and show methods of java.awt.Component have been deprecated for a
while.

The proper way to set the visibility
of a component is setVisible(boolean b)

Answer (score 0):

The method show() / hide() is deprecated means it's no longer supported and not usable. it is not good for future. we must replace .show() to setVisible(true). if we can't change now that was effect in future. so change that. i hope my answer is useful for all you guys..... Thank You From Umang Paneri.