# Difference between set visible and show method

Tags: java, swing, awt

In AWT Package, there are methods `setVisible()` & `show()` which does the same operation where does it actually get differ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `show()` method is the deprecated version of `setVisible()`, as is indicated in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show%28%29).

Also, an explanation of why is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636550/java-component-show-hide-are-deprecated-why).

Comment: If I am not wrong, setVisible() brings the window on focus too.

Comment: See the link below.  It appears to call show directly: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java/?v=source

Answer (score 5):

show() & hide() have been deprecated since JDK version 1.1 in preference of setVisible(boolean).

setVisible will show and hide a component where as show() will only show the component.